# Changes user's email on crowd doesn't apply in confluence

Tags: email, confluence, crowd

It's my configuration:
Atlassian Crowd Version: 2.0.2 (Build:#409 - 06-10-2009)
Atlassian Confluence 3.0.2

I can't change users' emails in Confluence because I use Crowd as external user management. So I have to change users' emails in Crowd but changes doesn't apply in Confluence. Even users has access to crowd user console and can login to Crowd and view their profile and edit their email password but changed emails doesn't apply in Confluence.
What should I do? Is it a bug?

Also I should mention that emails contains dot character(.).
I posted my question to Atlassian forum 3 days ago but there's no answer yet!
http://forums.atlassian.com/message.jspa?messageID=257342171